# Sumifs function with a criteria as a date to be equal with another date

Tags: excel, if-statement, sumifs

I want to have in sumifs  function, a criteria as a date to be equal with another date. I’ve tried:

```
=SUMIFS($N11:$AE11,$N11:$AE11,"<>0",$N9:$AE9,"<"&DATE(YEAR(FX11),MONTH(FX11),DAY(FX11)),$N9:$AE9,">"&DATE(YEAR(FX11),MONTH(FX11),DAY(FX11)))
```

But it seems it doesn’t work.
Thanks.

Comment: If `FX11` contains a real date, you can just use that instead of your `DATE(...` function.   If it does not contain a real date, your `DATE(...` function will not work.  Also, your formula requires that your `criteria_range` be simultaneously `greater than` and `less than` the date in `FX11`.  This is a logical impossibility.  If this comment is not helpful, please edit your question to explain what *doesn't work* means.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `FX11` contains a real date, and you want your criteria to be equal to it, then try:

```
=SUMIF($N$9:$AE$9,FX11,$N$11:$AE$11)
```

If `FX11` contains a date/time, then try:

```
=SUMIF($N$9:$AE$9,INT(FX11),$N$11:$AE$11)
```

Excel stores date/time as number of days and fractions of a day with `1 Jan 1900` = `1` (usually); so the `INT` function will remove the time portion.

And, in doing a `SUM`, there is no need to test that an entry is non-zero since `x + 0 = x`